# Create a bargraph/pie chart of column sums in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this with age brackets:

```
new_id                            18-24  25-34  35-44  45-54  55-64  65-74  75-84  85-89  89+
001722E206AD9FB2F1F92C5FD8596DB0    0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0     0
003C2920AB9521CA6D1CDDDBB85E4772    0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0     0
0066C5FD1F7FE804049C508C026F0E59    0      0      0      0      1      1      0      0     0
006B78D4236C00D2D8C8F31035B2A480    0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0     0
0077D1B650F50D8E32974C12C3765CF4    0      0      0      1      1      0      0      0     0
FFD6674A1F3B4FECC66E51E3789441A4    0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0     0
FFD9B3CB3B7FD6B8CAE595418918B178    0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0     0
FFDA6E8C77B3FD7ADA405ED9F5A88A86    0      0      0      0      1      1      0      0     0
FFE591AE9E3B1B9E69CBF0F035BDEEFE    0      1      1      0      0      0      0      0     0
FFE7FA11CE3E1540DE079B3768E9F7E0    0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0     0
```

Want I want to do is sum each column and represent the total of each age bracket using a bar graph and/or a piechart in python. "new_id" would be ignored. I just want to create an age distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sum the columns and create a bar plot. `df[df.columns[1:]]` will skip the `new_id` column:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

str = '''new_id                   18-24  25-34  35-44  45-54  55-64  65-74  75-84  85-89  89+
001722E206AD9FB2F1F92C5FD8596DB0    0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0     0
003C2920AB9521CA6D1CDDDBB85E4772    0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0     0
0066C5FD1F7FE804049C508C026F0E59    0      0      0      0      1      1      0      0     0
006B78D4236C00D2D8C8F31035B2A480    0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0     0
0077D1B650F50D8E32974C12C3765CF4    0      0      0      1      1      0      0      0     0
FFD6674A1F3B4FECC66E51E3789441A4    0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0     0
FFD9B3CB3B7FD6B8CAE595418918B178    0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0     0
FFDA6E8C77B3FD7ADA405ED9F5A88A86    0      0      0      0      1      1      0      0     0
FFE591AE9E3B1B9E69CBF0F035BDEEFE    0      1      1      0      0      0      0      0     0
FFE7FA11CE3E1540DE079B3768E9F7E0    0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0     0'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(str), delim_whitespace=True)
df[df.columns[1:]].sum().plot.bar(rot=0, color='DarkTurquoise')
plt.show()
```

[image: example bar plot]

For a pie chart: `df[df.columns[1:]].sum().plot.pie()`

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Worked perfectly!